# Where are the weapons and ammunition used by Russia coming from?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, military, ukraine, weapons

Are the weapons and ammunition used by Russia in the Ukrainian war coming from their preexisting storage?

Or, have they increased their production since the start of the war?

Comment: Probably all stockpile because production takes time. There are three slightly different questions in here.

Comment: Yes,this is "almost" domestic production, from the big stockpile, including old soviet models - most of them are. There are only few!!! from models or "new weaps like T14, or SU35 made only to show good picture on TV. New weaponst require foreign parts and also are made very slow. So in current state, the production is not sufficient and will decline

Comment: The general Russian military strategy since the USSR has been preparing for another WWII, i.e. a multi-year total war with the population mobilized.

Answer (score 6):

No sane military will release the information you are asking for in real time, so this is a bit speculative.

Even without the worldwide supply chain problems induced by COVID-19, it takes a good deal of time, a lot more than two months, to ramp up production of complex machinery such as tanks and jet fighters. The supply chain problems can only make matters worse. Even guns, which are much simpler to build, face supply chain and logistics issues.

Devices that are even easier to manufacture such as bullets are a different matter. Whether Russia has increased bullet production, who knows? (Other than Russia itself, of course.) As I wrote at the outset, no sane military willingly releases that information in real time. Other countries will try to piece together a picture through spying, etc., but that takes time.

Comment: So, the answer is that nobody here knows for sure? But maybe educated guess are possible like how much military material production can be increased typically judging by other past experiences.

Comment: @Trilarion How could one possible know for sure? Countries do not release their military production, at least not in real time, and that is what the question asks for. Wars are won or lost with logistics -- and with determining the logistics capabilities of the opponent.

Comment: Yes, but still maybe educated guesses are possible judging by post experiences. Just take any other country that kind of resembles the situation of Russia and try to give some confidence intervals based on them, if possible. It's okay if there is an error as long as it is not overly large.

Comment: No country will release this information, but the flip side seems to be that intelligence agencies would like to know this. And it would seem to me that with all the spy satellites in orbit, they'd have a pretty good idea about truck and train traffic. It seems a safe bet that the CIA knows where each Russian tank factory is, and how active they are (are they working weekends?)